# R: Extract values from a summary() in a clValid object

Tags: r, function, cluster-analysis

I'm working on validating the goodness of hierarchical clustering using clValid. Below is my code. The clustering always results in one noisy cluster which contains the 70% of the elements and hence I recursively cluster the elements in the noisy cluster.

```
intern <- clValid(primaryDataSource, 2:10,clMethods = c("Hierarchical"),
                  validation="internal", maxitems = 2200)
summary(intern)
```

Output of summary(intern):

```
Clustering Methods:
 hierarchical 

Cluster sizes:
 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

Validation Measures:
                                 2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10

hierarchical Connectivity   3.8738  3.8738  8.2563 10.9452 16.0286 18.6452 20.6452 22.6452 24.6452
             Dunn           4.0949  0.8810  0.6569  0.8694  0.8808  1.0416  1.0230  1.0262  1.3724
             Silhouette     0.9592  0.9879  0.9785  0.9751  0.9727  0.9729  0.9727  0.9726  0.9725

Optimal Scores:

             Score  Method       Clusters
Connectivity 3.8738 hierarchical 2       
Dunn         4.0949 hierarchical 2       
Silhouette   0.9879 hierarchical 3
```

At each iteration I have to execute the clValid() and select the number of clusters which would give me the highest Silhouette value (in the above example it's 3). I'm trying to automate the recursive clustering approach. Hence I'm looking to pick the number of clusters which would have the highest Silhouette value. Can you please help me in extracting that piece of information? Thank you.

P.S: I tried converting the results into a data frame or a table. However it didn't work.

**Update: After using str()**

```
> str(intern)

Formal class 'clValid' [package "clValid"] with 14 slots
  ..@ clusterObjs:List of 1
  .. ..$ hierarchical:List of 7
  .. .. ..$ merge      : int [1:2173, 1:2] -1673 -714 -1121 -1688 -1876 -1123 -1689 -1228 -429 -535 ...
  .. .. ..$ height     : num [1:2173] 0 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 ...
  .. .. ..$ order      : int [1:2174] 2165 2166 1950 1951 1954 1955 1577 1565 1564 1576 ...
  .. .. ..$ labels     : chr [1:2174] "out_M_aacald_c_boundary" "out_M_12ppd_DASH_R_e_boundary" "out_M_12ppd_DASH_S_e_boundary" "in_M_14glucan_e_boundary" ...
  .. .. ..$ method     : chr "average"
  .. .. ..$ call       : language hclust(d = Dist, method = method)
  .. .. ..$ dist.method: chr "euclidean"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "hclust"
  ..@ measures   : num [1:3, 1:9, 1] 3.874 4.095 0.959 3.874 0.881 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Connectivity" "Dunn" "Silhouette"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:9] "2" "3" "4" "5" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr "hierarchical"
  ..@ measNames  : chr [1:3] "Connectivity" "Dunn" "Silhouette"
  ..@ clMethods  : chr "hierarchical"
  ..@ labels     : chr [1:2174] "out_M_aacald_c_boundary" "out_M_12ppd_DASH_R_e_boundary" "out_M_12ppd_DASH_S_e_boundary" "in_M_14glucan_e_boundary" ...
  ..@ nClust     : num [1:9] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..@ validation : chr "internal"
  ..@ metric     : chr "euclidean"
  ..@ method     : chr "average"
  ..@ neighbSize : num 10
  ..@ annotation : NULL
  ..@ GOcategory : chr "all"
  ..@ goTermFreq : num 0.05
  ..@ call       : language clValid(obj = primaryDataSource, nClust = 2:10, clMethods = c("Hierarchical"), validation = "internal",      maxitems = 2200)
```

I guess the important section is

```
@ measures   : num [1:3, 1:9, 1] 3.874 4.095 0.959 3.874 0.881 ...
      .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
      .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Connectivity" "Dunn" "Silhouette"
      .. .. ..$ : chr [1:9] "2" "3" "4" "5" ...
      .. .. ..$ : chr "hierarchical"
```

when I executed `>intern@measures`I got the below result.

```
                     2         3         4          5          6          7          8         9
Connectivity 3.8738095 3.8738095 8.2563492 10.9452381 16.0285714 18.6452381 20.6452381 22.645238
Dunn         4.0948837 0.8810494 0.6568857  0.8694067  0.8808228  1.0415614  1.0230197  1.026192
Silhouette   0.9591803 0.9879153 0.9784684  0.9751393  0.9727454  0.9728736  0.9727153  0.972622
                     10
Connectivity 24.6452381
Dunn          1.3724494
Silhouette    0.9725379
```

I'm able to get the max and access individual items based on the index. I want to get the maximum value for Silhouette.

```
intern@measures[1]
max(intern@measures)
```

Comment: assign it. `x <- summary(intern)`.

Comment: to inspect which elements you need from summary you could use `str(summary(intern))`

Comment: I've tried assigning before and it didn't work. The variable x is null.

Comment: @Stereo thank you for your answer. I think it should be str(intern). However I got the variable which stores the particular piece of information. It's intern@measure. It has a bit confusing list structure. Will you be able to provide further help? I have modified my answer with the new output.

Comment: Can you just do `max(intern@measures[3,,])`? And since you would prefer to find which of them is the max, not just what the max value is, how about `which.max(intern@measures[3,,])` (returns the number 2) or `dimnames(intern@measures)[[2]][which.max(intern@measures[3,,])]` (returns the string "3").

Comment: @r2evans thanks a lot. This one worked!

Answer (score 1):

Some additionnal explanation, when `str()` shows `@` signs, this points that the object you are inspecting is a `S4` class with attributes. I am not familiar with `clValid` but a quick look at the [source code](https://github.com/cran/clValid/blob/master/R/clValid-Classes.R) shows that the `clValid` class inherits from `S4`.

You can access those using `object@attribute`. Typically these attributes can be anything.

Looking at the `print` [function](https://github.com/cran/clValid/blob/master/R/clValid-Methods.R#L70) for `clValid` it seems that you can access the measures using the convenience function `measures(object)`. Looking at the remaining source code for `clValid` there are [utility functions](https://github.com/cran/clValid/blob/master/R/clValid-Methods.R#L145) that may be of use for you. Check `optimalScores()`.